# How hard is it to link a hardened BIP32 child public key to it's parent public key?

Tags: elliptic-curves, key-derivation, cryptocurrency

The BIP32 spec says this in the [security section](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki#security):

```
Note however that the following properties does not exist:
 * Given a parent extended public key (Kpar,cpar) and a child public key (Ki), it is hard to find i.
```

The spec doesn't say that this line is valid only for keys that are not hardened.
Is this true even if the child is hardened?

Comment: The hardened keys go through a hash function.  So as long as sha256 is irreversible, the parent key should be safe.